# Restricting tenants from base URL

Tags: django

I have a set of URLs I wouldn't want to be accessed by tenants. For example, a sign-up page for creating new tenants. I only want it to be accessible from the base URL. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the solution is to define the public URL or the URL for the base application in as the PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF in the settings.py file.
That is PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'app_with_tenant_model.urls'